# how to define methods that use the variables of some other controller in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In My rails application I have two controllers namely tweets_controller and coordinates_controller.In my final view I want to display the attributes of tweets_controller using the condition in coordinates_controller. The problem I am facing is that tweets_controller should know the variables of coordinates_controller.
my code for coordinates_controller

```
def CoordinatesHelper.query()
  a = Coordinates.where(city: params[:show])
  b = a.first
  if a.count == 1
    latitude = b.latitude
    longitude= b.longitude
  end

  if(latitude=0 && longitude=0) 
    sql="Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND user_loc LIKE 'show' order by id desc LIMIT 30"
  else if (latitude!=0 && longitude!=0) 
         min_lat = latitude - 1.0
         max_lat = latitude + 1.0
         min_lng = longitude - 1.0
         max_lng =  longitude + 1.0
         sql = "Select * from tweets where tweet_text LIKE '%text%' AND ( ((longitude BETWEEN min_lng and max_lng) AND (latitude BETWEEN min_lat and max_lat)) OR (user_loc LIKE 'show') ) order by id desc LIMIT 30"
       else
         sql="Select * from  tweets where tweet_text LIKE  '%text%' LIMIT 30"
       end  

  end
end
```

My  tweets_controller just displays the attributes of the tweets table .using the definition 'index' in the tweets_controller.The conditions such as latitude,longitude comes from coordinates table, is there any way by which the tweets_controller will be able to evaluate the coordinates table latitude, longitude and then display the tweets in the final view. To be precise the coordinates_controller has variables  latitude,longitude and city,and params[:show] in the search button. The tweets_controller should have access to the attributes of coordinates_controller. How should I do that?

```
<%= @tweets.each do |tweets| %>

<ul>

  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>

  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
<li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
<li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>

</ul>
<% end %>
```

This is the final view content and to display this, the conditions  of latitude and longitude are in coordinates table

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is an association at the model level in between the Tweet model and Coordinate model, like this:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :coordinate
end
```

this tells that a tweet have coordinate.

the problem is not about accessing variables from one controller to another(that should never happen unless it is parent-child controllers)
but the problem is that you dont associations between models properly setup.

Comment: by including  this association and using helper methods of coordinates_controller in tweets_controller will it be possible to access the coordinates inside tweets _controller?